# Cannot find module error while ionic release build (android)

Tags: android, angular, ionic4, release, production

Error while building android app with --prod flag
Currently, I've tried adding the display page module to app.module.ts but it didn't work.

```
ERROR in : Cannot determine the module for class DisplayPage in E:/innoventa 2k20 playstore/innoventa 2k20/src/app/display/display.page.ts! Add DisplayPage to the NgModule to fix it.
```

my app.module.ts file is

```
import { DisplayPageModule } from './display/display.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, GroupInfoPipe, FeedbackPipe],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    RubricPageModule,
    NgxQRCodeModule,
    DisplayPageModule
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    AngularFireAuth,
    BarcodeScanner,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy ,},
    ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This is my folder structure

[image: The problem is with display page module]

Comment: What is this page? Is it presented in modal or what?

Comment: @MostafaHarb It is a simple ionic page present in the app directory.

Comment: If its a normal page then there is no need to put it inside imports...

Comment: @MostafaHarb Yeah, This solution worked and also I used only --release flag previously I was using both --release and --prod flag. Thanks!